# how to change value of textbox based on another textbox in wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am binding list to datagrid in WPF

in this grid there are 2 textboxes among them one is readonly.
now when I enter any value in textbox it will automatically insert into read only textbox of datagrid

anyone knows how can I get the readonly textbox and assign value to it ?

Comment: You should try marking some of your questions as 'answered'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very important that you read the FAQ and post your question.You need to write the code  and then ask for any assistance.

The solution to your  problem is **WPF DataBinding** . ([Read more about it here](http://wpftutorial.net/DataBindingOverview.html))

Here is an example which reflects your situation

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions >
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Name="SourceTextBox" Grid.Row="0" >Hello World</TextBox>
    <TextBox Name="DestTextbox" Text="{Binding ElementName=SourceTextBox,Path=Text}" Grid.Row="1" IsEnabled="False"></TextBox>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really getting the question but as I see it you either want:

a. To assign a default value to the readonly textbox which is simple, you just assign a 'Name' in xaml and then use it in code or

b. You want to use the data that is stored in the readonly textbox which is done again by assigning a 'Name' in xaml and then use it in code.

Comment: I want to store data from another textbox which is not read only.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBox Name="Text1" >
<TextBox Name="Text2" IsReadOnly="True" 
   Text="{Binding Text,ElementName=Text1,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```